# How can I make the terminal clear the screen before auto-logging me out of an ssh session due to inactivity?

Tags: session, ssh, timeout, logout

When being logged out of an ssh session due to inactivity, the previous commands run on the terminal and their outputs are still visible on the screen. I want to clear the screen when the session gets timed out(I understand they can still scroll up and see the command history, but that is alright for now). The TMOUT variable is set to log out after 30 minutes (1800 sec). How can I do this?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Stackoverflow is for help with software development. You should consider asking this on [su] or [unix.se].

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + L (clear the screen)
reset (re-initialise the terminal)